# Append text in textarea in AngularJS with Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, textarea

I an new to AngularJS.

Below is my try to append text value in textarea with Laravel.

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="eticket" ng-model="{{ $var[0]['info'] }}"></textarea>
```

But it is generate error like [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=day1&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=11&p3=Itinerary).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your expression .You dont need to pass curly braces in ng-model . ng-model is angular js directive and you can directly pass value like :

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="eticket" ng-model="$var[0]['info']">
```